# Four-dimensional Dirac delta from a Green's function

Tags: mathematical-physics, dirac-delta, greens-function

Consider four-dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{C}$ with coordinates $w=x,y,z,\bar{z}$. Define $D^i = (\partial_x,\partial_y,4\partial_z)$, and consider the following equation for a Green's function:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\pi}(D^iD^k)\Delta_{k\ell}(w,w') 
= \,\delta^i_{\,\ell}\,\delta^{(4)}(w-w')\,.
\end{equation}
The solution is supposed to be
\begin{equation}
\label{PropagatoronM}
\Delta_{ij}(w,w')  = -\frac{c}{4\pi}\varepsilon_{ijk}D^k\bigg(\frac{1}{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')(\bar{z}-\bar{z}')}\bigg) \,.
\end{equation}

Away from $w=w'$, this is obvious from the antisymmetry of the Levi-Civita tensor. However, it is not clear to me why this is the case for $w=w'$. In fact, by computing $D^k\Delta_{kl}$ explicitly, I obtain zero. What am I missing?

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/691550/2451